# HBase keyvalue (NOSQL) to Hive table (SQL)

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have some tables in Hive that I need to join together. Since I need to do some work on each of them, normalize the key, remove outliers.... and as I add more and more tables... This chaining process turned out to be a big mass. 
It is so easy to get lost where you are and the query is getting out of control.

However, I have a pretty clear idea how the final table should look like and each column is fairly independent of the other tables.

For examp, here is an example:

```
table_class1 
name id score
Alex 1  90
Chad 3  50
...

table_class2
name      id score
Alexandar 1  50
Benjamin  2  100
...
```

In the end I really want something looks like:

```
name id class1 class2 ...
alex 1  90     50
ben  2  100    NA  
chad 3  50     NA
```

I know it could be a left outer join, but I am really having a hard time to create a seperate table for each of them after the normalization and then use left outer join with the union of the `keys` to left outer join each of them...

I am thinking about using NOSQL(HBase) to dump the processed data into NOSQL format.. like:

```
(source, key, variable, value)
(table_class1, (alex, 1), class1, 90)
(table_class1, (chad, 3), class1, 50)
(table_class2, (alex, 1), class2, 50)
(table_class2, (benjamin, 2), class2, 100)
...
```

In the end, I want to use something like the `melt` and `cast` in R [reshape](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) package to bring that data back to be a table.

Since this is a big data project, and there will be hundreds of millions of key value pairs in HBase.

(1) I don't know if this is a legit approach

(2) If so, is there any big data tool to pivot long HBase table into a Hive table.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to keep highly normalized data structure in Hive. Hive is not a traditional database which requires well design schema and can handle joins very well. As to me, the final result you wanted is a better table structure for hive rather than keep a few normalized tables.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would love to help more, but I am not clear about what you're trying to achieve (maybe because I've never used R), please elaborate and I'll try to improve my answer if necessary.

Why do you need HBase for? You can store your processed data in new tables and work with them, you can even `CREATE VIEW` to simplify the query if it's too large, maybe that's what you're looking for ([HIVE manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual)). Unless you have a good reason for using HBase, I'll stick just to HIVE to avoid additional complexity, don't get me wrong, there are a lot of valid reasons for using HBase.

About your second question, you can define and use HBase tables as HIVE tables, you can even `CREATE` and `SELECT INSERT` into them all inside HIVE, is that what you're looking for?: [HBase/HIVE integration doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)

One last thing in case you don't know, you can create custom functions in HIVE very easily to help you with the tedious normalization process, take a look at [this](http://blog.spryinc.com/2013/09/a-guide-to-user-defined-functions-in.html).